# Dynamically get values of object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Let's say I have an Object `myBook` and an array `allCategories`.

```
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];

const myBook = {
   isItScienceFiction: true,
   isItManga: false,
   isItForKids: false
}
```

**What I want :** Loop over categories to check the value of Book, for example, check if `"sciencefiction"` exists in my Book Object and then check it's value

**What I have tried :**

1) With `indexOf`

```
allCategories.map((category) => {
    Object.keys(myBook).indexOf(category) 
    // Always returns -1 because "sciencefiction" doesn't match with "isItScienceFiction"
});
```

2) With `includes`

```
allCategories.map((category) => {
    Object.keys(myBook).includes(category) 
    // Always returns false because "sciencefiction" doesn't match with "isItScienceFiction"
});
```

**Expected output :**

```
allCategories.map((category) => {
   // Example 1 : Returns "sciencefiction" because "isItScienceFiction: true"
   // Example 2 : Returns nothing because "isItManga: false"
   // Example 3 : Returns nothing because there is not property in myBook with the word "school"
   // Example 4 : Returns nothing because there is not property in myBook with the word "art"


   // If category match with myBook categories and the value is true then
    return (
         <p>{category}</p>
    );
});
```

If you need more information, just let me know, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Well... you could loop over all book keys, remove "isIt", then lowercase it...? Not sure what exactly you're asking, since you seem to already know exactly why your approach fails.

Comment: Not very sure,but cant you convert the keys to a single case and then compare?

Comment: Such inputs are ugly. I mean, there is no guarantee that lowercase will **always** solve the issue. Is there any other relation available between the object and the category?

Comment: Seems like a bad data design, why doesn't my book just have an array of categories?

Comment: @briosheje There's no relation between the categories and the book. The categories is a list of categories stored in an API and the book have a boolean with each categories `isIt<Category>` in the database

Comment: @KévinHuang then the best you can do is either extract the lowercase part after isIt or use a regex. There isn't much else to do with such a pattern, what scares me, though, is that it's not a **solid pattern**, hence the chance of it failing for unknown or unpredictable reasons is quite high.

Comment: I would prefer myBook to have this structure, so that the absence of a category means it is not applicable to the book. That way you won't have to change ALL books once you implement isItForRobots in 3 years: `const myBook = { types: [ 'sciencefiction' ]}; const myBook2 = { types: [ 'kids', 'sciencefiction' ]};`. Then your problem disappears by itself. If the API can't be changed, do this transformation yourself before using the books, using the string manipulation mentioned above.

Comment: Can you please post the expected output?

Comment: I'm guessing you want `filter` instead of `map`? Anyway, as briosheje said, this is badly designed and error prone.

Comment: @briosheje I'll check if I can do a regex and I'm know it's some bad data design, since I can't change the data design, I'll check the regex way and tell you when I have a result of it :)

Comment: @KévinHuang perhaps try to provide a larger data set so that we may be able to come up with a workaround. As Shilly said above, building an object with that structure would help, since it will be easier to track errors. That `myBook` object is the devil of your code, right now.

Comment: Why the downvote please ? Have I said something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `filter` and `find` methods to return new array of categories and then use `map` method to return array of elements.

```js
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];
const myBook = {isItScienceFiction: true, isItManga: false, isItForKids: false}

const result = allCategories.filter(cat => {
  const key = Object.keys(myBook).find(k => k.slice(4).toLowerCase() === cat);
  return myBook[key]
}).map(cat => `<p>${cat}</p>`)

console.log(result)
```

You can also use `reduce` instead of `filter` and `map` and `endsWith` method.

```js
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];
const myBook = {isItScienceFiction: true,isItManga: false,isItForKids: false}

const result = allCategories.reduce((r, cat) => {
  const key = Object.keys(myBook).find(k => k.toLowerCase().endsWith(cat));
  if(myBook[key]) r.push(`<p>${cat}</p>`)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Object.keys(myBook).forEach(function(key){console.log(myBook[key])})
```

... place you code instead of `console.log`. This can do the trick without hard coding and also the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

You should really not keep a number of properties containing booleans. While that might work for 1, 2 or 3 categories, for a few hundred it won't work well. Instead, just store the categories in an array:

```
 const myBook = {
   categories: ["sciencefiction", "manga", "kids"],
 };
```

If you got some object with the old structure already, you can easily convert them:

```
 const format = old => {
  const categories = [];

  if(old.isItScienceFiction)
    categories.push("sciencefiction");
  if(old.isItManga)
     categories.push("manga");
  if(old.isItForKids)
     categories.push("kids");

   return { categories };
 };
```

Now to check wether a book contains a certain category:

```
  const isManga = myBook.categories.includes("manga");
```

And your rendering is also quite easy now:

```
 myBook.categories.map(it => <p>{it}</p>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the the categories and keys of object:

```js
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"],
      myBook = { isItScienceFiction:true, isItManga:false, isItForKids:false }

const map = Object.keys(myBook)
                   .reduce((r, k) => r.set(k.slice(4).toLowerCase(), k), new Map);

/* map:
   {"sciencefiction" => "isItScienceFiction"}
   {"manga" => "isItManga"}
   {"forkids" => "isItForKids"}
*/

allCategories.forEach(key => {
  let keyInObject = map.get(key); // the key name in object
  let value = myBook[keyInObject]; // value for the key in object
  
  console.log(key, keyInObject, value)

  if(keyInObject && value) {
    // do something if has the current key and the value is true
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.filter()` and `Array.find()` with a RegExp to find categories that have matching keys. Use `Array.map()` to convert the categories to strings/JSX/etc...

```js
const findMatchingCategories = (obj, categories) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  
  return allCategories
    .filter(category => {
      const pattern = new RegExp(category, 'i');
      
      return obj[keys.find(c => pattern.test(c))];
    })
    .map(category => `<p>${category}</p>`);
};

const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];

const myBook = {
   isItScienceFiction: true,
   isItManga: false,
   isItForKids: false
};

const result = findMatchingCategories(myBook, allCategories);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```js
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];

const myBook = {
  isItScienceFiction: true,
  isItManga: false,
  isItForKids: false
};

const myBookKeys = Object.keys(myBook);

const result = allCategories.map(category => {
  const foundIndex = myBookKeys.findIndex(y => y.toLowerCase().includes(category.toLowerCase()));
  
  if (foundIndex > -1 && myBook[myBookKeys[foundIndex]])
    return `<p>${category}</p>`;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the key names in `myBook` object for easy lookup like:

```
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];

const myBook = {
  isItScienceFiction: true,
  isItManga: false,
  isItForKids: false
}

const modBook = {}

Object.keys(myBook).map((key) => {
  const modKey = key.slice(4).toLowerCase()
  modBook[modKey] = myBook[key]
})

const haveCategories = allCategories.map((category) => {
  if (modBook[category]) {
    return <p>{category}</p>
  }
  return null
})
console.log(haveCategories)
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting `sciencefiction` to `isItScienceFiction` is not possible and looping all the keys of `myBook` for every `category` is not optimal.

But converting `isItScienceFiction` to `sciencefiction` is pretty easy, so you can create `newMyBook` from your`myBook` and use it instead to check.

Creating `newMyBook` is a one time overhead.

```js
const allCategories = ["sciencefiction", "manga", "school", "art"];
const myBook = {isItScienceFiction: true,isItManga: false,isItForKids: false};

const newMyBook = Object.keys(myBook).reduce((a, k) => {
    return { ...a, [k.replace('isIt', '').toLowerCase()]: myBook[k] };
}, {});

console.log(
    allCategories.filter(category => !!newMyBook[category]).map(category => `<p>${category}</p>`)
);
```